# Teaplix Inventory CSV Order is not importing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, csv

I am using Teaplix To import Inventory Quantity Upload.
https://www.teapplix.com/help/?page_id=4720

CSV upload

```
url = "https://www.teapplix.com/h/#{@account_name}/ea/admin.php?User=#{@username}&Passwd=#{@password}&Action=Upload&Subaction=inventory&upload=#{csv_url}"
response = HTTParty.post(url,
      body: {}.to_json,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type" => "text/csv",
        "Accept" => "text/csv"
      }
    )
```

Everything i am grtting, but csv is not uploading

Getting Error

```
error "No such run-mode 'Upload'"
```

can some one tell which way i can upload inventory csv in teaplix .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API is deprecated now:

> Teapplix V1 API is accessed via URL end point "app.teapplix.com". As
>   of January 2017, this API is deprecated and only maintained "as-is",
>   with no functional updates or bug fixes. New customers or applications
>   should use V2 API. While existing applications can continue to use
>   this API indefinitely, you are encouraged to migrate to V2 API (REST +
>   JSON) if you seek additional capabilities and bug fixes.

Teapplix supports HTTP API to upload / download data.

> www.teapplix.com

Api end point

```
https://api.teapplix.com/api2
```

By using curl i am able to solve my issue

> curl -k --form Subaction=Inventory --form upload=@upload.csv
>   'https://app.teapplix.com/h/demo/ea/api.php?User=xx&Passwd=yy&Action=Upload'